# Container not apply background color to all floats inside it

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to add a background-color to a container with three div class floats inside: one at the top, and two side-by-side beneath it. When I add a bg color to the .site-container in CSS, it is only adding a bg color to div class=top. How can I get the background to cover div class=left and right as well? Thank you! Here's my CSS code:

```
body{
    background-color:white;
}

.site-container{
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    background-color: blue;

}

.clr{
    clear:both;
}

.left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.right{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
```

HTML code:

```
 <body>
        <div class="site-container">
            <div class="top">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia deleniti odio quae eligendi ab voluptatibus eos praesentium, eaque repellendus, nulla nostrum voluptate sit voluptates officia explicabo cum laboriosam dolorem architecto.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="left">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi ex amet voluptates nemo libero aliquid aperiam tempore error ratione molestiae, voluptate rerum eaque vero! Quibusdam corporis quidem dolorum eum aliquam.</p>
            </div>
            

            <div class="right">
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, pariatur, temporibus officiis doloribus atque hic deleniti officia dolorem sit optio magni facilis laborum, quos doloremque quasi laudantium vero! Adipisci, voluptates!</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

I switched the position of the float clear fixes and I'm not sure what else to do... very beginner!